# Django Models Foreign Key Field Match

Tags: python, django, django-models, string-matching

I have the following Django Model -

```
class M(models.Model):
    ...
    disp_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)
    ...

class XX(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey(User)
    y = models.ForeignKey(M, unique=True)
```

Now in my views.py, I want to do a partial string match on all items in `XX` with the field y.disp_name.

Normally one would do this - `M.objects.filter(disp_name__istartswith='string')`

But here `M` is a foreignkey in `Model XX`. So if I do `XX.objects.filter(y.disp_name__istartswith='string')` I get an error.

Also, this too fails -
`u = User.objects.get(id=1)
u.xx_set.filter(y.disp_name__istartswith='string')`

Exception that I get says is - `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression (<console>, line 1)`

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish you had used proper field names rather than X, Y and M - it's really hard to follow.

But in any case, you should always use the double-underscore syntax to follow relations on the left hand side of the filter expression:

```
XX.objects.filter(y__disp_name__istartswith='string')
```

(The technical reason for this is that the parameters to `filter` are actually keyword arguments to a function, so the left-hand side of that has to be a string rather than an expression.)

Comment: Sorry, company rules. Thanks, that solved the problem! So django splits the LHS part on '__' & uses it as fields?

Comment: Yes, pretty much, although naturally it's more complicated than that because of the need to distinguish the joins from the lookup type (`in`, `istartswith`, etc). See the code in `django.db.models.sql.query.Query.add_filter` if you're interested.